# replace words depend on second line

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a netlist file. It has split lines. The split sign is '+' at the beginning of the continuation line.

```
MP1 Y A VDD VDD pch_25 W=1u L=550n M=1
MP0 Y B
+VDD VDD pch_25 W=1u L=550n M=1
MN1 v0 A VSS VSS nch_25_dnw W=500.0n L=550n M=1
MN0 Y B v0 VSS nch_25_dnw W=500.0n L=550n M=1
```

I'd like to replace the beginning "M" of each line with "X" if that (complete) line contains "pch_25", so the desired output is

```
XP1 Y A VDD VDD pch_25 W=1u L=550n M=1
XP0 Y B
+VDD VDD pch_25 W=1u L=550n M=1
MN1 v0 A VSS VSS nch_25_dnw W=500.0n L=550n M=1
MN0 Y B v0 VSS nch_25_dnw W=500.0n L=550n M=1
```

I have the following (working) command:

```
sed -e :a -e '$!N;s/\n+/\\/;ta' -e 'P;D' file \
                                        | sed '/pch_25/s/^M/X/' | sed -e 's/\\/\n+/g'
```

How to replace this command with a single `sed` without pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, you would do tasks like this with the `N;P;D` pattern in `sed` to always keep two lines together in the buffer. Unfortunally, netlist file can split one record over more than one line, so the usual solution won't work.

The obvious solution is to add a loop to collect all lines that belong together:

```
sed -e :a -e '/pch_25/s/^M/X/;/\n[^+]/!{N;ba' -e '};P;D' file
```

- `/pch_25/s/^M/X/` is the actual replacement we want to perform: In lines containing `pch_25`, `s`ubstitute the leading (`^` anchor) `M` with `X`.
- The pattern `\n[^+]` defines a line break followed by some other character than `+`, which indicates that we added one line too much and have to exit the loop. In other words, if we invert the match with `!`, we can append the next line with `N` and `ba` jumps to our loop mark `:a`
- Finally, the usual `P;D` prints and removes the first line of the buffer, starting a new cycle with the rest. And yes, if we already collected more than two lines in the buffer, only the first will get printed and removed. But no problem: The next cycle won't replace anything, because the pattern will start with `+`, not `M` and the other lines will get removed one after another

**Advanced solution:**
Now I had an idea to expand the `N;P;D` pattern to go multi-line without jump mark and `b`. The idea is to use `D` for looping by adding newlines to the beginning of the pattern which can be removed by the `D` (note: this is GNU `sed` code):

```
sed '/pch_25/s/^M/X/;/\n[^+]/!N;//P;//!s/^/\n/;D' file
```

- `/\n[^+]/!N` adds a newline if we are still in the same net record
- `//` repeats the last pattern, here without inversion, so if we added one line too much, we can `P`rint the first part
- `//!s/^/\n/` adds a newline to the start of the pattern, if we are still inside one record, so the final
- `D` will remove only the added empty line before starting over, if we have to check for replacement or remove the first line that got already printed if we are already in the next record

Unfortunally, using `\n` in the replacement is a non-standard addition of GNU `sed`, so you can't rely on it and have to find another way to add a newline, for example appending to the hold space, emptying pattern space and `x`changing spaces:

```
sed '/pch_25/s/^M/X/;/\n[^+]/!N;//P;//!{H;s/.*//;x;};D' file
```